# Firestore: granular restriction of document names on create via firestore.rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How can I enforce document names when user is creating a document?
What I want to achieve is that the last three letters of the document name match the first 3 letters of `auth.uid`. I found a workaround by using firebase functions, but would prefer a firestore.rules solution.

Example:

uid: XXXcqwrrqweqwe

doc: 24rrqsdferXXX (valid)

doc: werfsdfsdfXXY (invalid)

Comment: The variable you use in the path (e.g. `{doc}`) should be a string that you can put a regex on. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I was thinking in that direction but I can't make it work as in example given (last three letters to be same as first three of uid). In the end I ended up using a callable function.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried in security rules. That really is the best way to increase the chances we can help.

Comment: @radulle Can you share which approach have you tried in security rules?

Comment: I tried using regex and it would work for the whole uid, what I'm having problem is getting first three letters of uid and using them in the regex to validate document name.